# Jenkins dashboard report with customization

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to get the jenkins report as in this template:

[image]

so which plugin will help me to get such kind of report?

I have tried multiple plugins, but no luck. I have tried test analyzer report, dashboard view and jenkins matrix and trends plugin. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Hi , Welcome to stack overflow  .Please take the time to read to see [ask], We cannot help you if you do not provide any code, can you please put your code

Comment: I think Groovy scripts may help. can anyone help me on it?

Comment: @trupti was this question solved? I am having similar query..would like to know if u found any plugin to use?